# How to add JQuery (or any) js library into page loaded in Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, android-webview

How to add JQuery library into page loaded in Android WebView? My WebView with page:

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: embed the jqeury lib in the webpage with a script tag?

Comment: I'm trying this way: `web.loadUrl("javascript:"+"var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0); var oScript= document.createElement('script');\n oScript.type = \"text/javascript\"; oScript.src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js\"; oHead.appendChild( oScript);");`  but JQuery still doesn't work.

Comment: use an external html file instead of java code

Comment: What do you mean? I have to work with external website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove escapes from js code (like `\n`). Also I had to wait untill JQuery is loaded:

```
load.tryReady = function(time_elapsed) {  
   // Continually polls to see if jQuery is loaded.  
   if (typeof $ == "undefined") { // if jQuery isn't loaded yet...  
       if (time_elapsed <= 5000) { // and we havn't given up trying...  
           setTimeout("load.tryReady(" + (time_elapsed + 200) + ")", 200); // set a timer to check again in 200 ms.  
       } else {  
           alert("Timed out while loading jQuery.")  
       }  
   } else {  
      // Any code to run after jQuery loads goes here!  
   }  
}
```

http://www.coderanch.com/t/504284/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/dynamically-load-jQuery-javascript-library