# jquery prob in WebView of Android 4.4

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have loaded a webpage in thw WebView and inject jquery and my js file from my asset fole to that webpage. My code is below in short.

**MainActivity.java**

```
mWebView.loadUrl("www.test.com/test.html");
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: " + readFromfile("jquery-1.8.3.js", MainActivity.this));
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: " + readFromfile("my_android.js", MainActivity.this));

.....................

mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: myMethod();");
```

**my_android.js**

```
function myMethod(){
...............
var mySpan = $("<span id=\"myspan\"></span>");
................
}
```

This is running fine in pre-Kitkat. But it is giving error in Kitkat.
When it is loading the JS, it is giving error:

```
I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: varrootjQuery is not defined"
```

When I am calling the js function, it is giving:

```
$ is not defined
```

What is the problem in my code? Here I like to mention all webview related code are running in UI thread only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to wait jquery is loaded before use it.

See this similar problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12763180/1663074